# is it possible to call yahoo contact API in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, yahoo-api

in angular application I need to request yahoo contact API:
first i wanna know its possible to request from client or not?
my code in Angular is:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(q => {

      const body = {
        client_id: this.yahooObj.clientId,
        client_secret: this.yahooObj.clientSecret,
        redirect_uri: this.yahooObj.redirect,
        code: q.code,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      }
      this.http.post<any>('https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token',
        body, {headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(`${this.yahooObj.clientId}:${this.yahooObj.clientSecret}`)
          })})
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log('return data service', data);
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log('Error', err);
        });
  });
}

 yahooAuth() {
    window.open(`https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=${this.yahooObj.clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${this.yahooObj.redirect}`);
  }
```

and redirecting and beck code from yahoo authentication page works fine but http.post request back below Errors about CORS policy, since in postman works fine.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token' from origin 'http://localhost:3201' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

since in postman is okay and in browser have this CORS policy error, i need make sure there is any way to call this API in client?

Comment: It is possible, but you need to do Step1 and Step2 first, "get_token" is Step3. Please look at the API Doc https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `Basic` and the token. Try the following

```js
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${this.yahooObj.clientId}:${this.yahooObj.clientSecret}`)
```

Notice the space after the word `Basic`.

About the CORS issue, you could set up a proxy in the front-end to redirect the request.

Comment: thanks for replying, do you know how can i fetch contact list of yahoo from API?

Comment: I haven't used the API myself, but I did find this: https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Yahoo API call in backend server and call the API from angular client, it's so called proxy. Which can resolve the CORS problem.

Comment: thanks for replying, do you know how can i fetch contact list of yahoo from API?

Comment: You can issue a GET request to `https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts`

https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html